# What is this jet airliner flying over my house?

Tags: airliner, aircraft-identification

I took a picture of this jet flying over my house:
[image]

It looks like a 737. Took place on July 14, 2020 at 4:00 PM in Long Beach, California.

Comment: You should add the date, time and location. It's much easier to reference that with one of the tracking websites out there (eg fr24 or flightaware) than to try and identify an airliner from a few pixels.

Comment: Can't see exposed tires in the gear wells - definitely not a 737

Answer (score 7):

The position of the sun's reflection on the fuselage nose shows that it is positioned very low – a clear indication of an Embraer type. The lower wing sweep and the long tailcone also indicate as much and are a clear indication against a larger twin like the Boeing 737 or the A320.

This leaves the [E 179, 175, 190 or 195](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embraer_E-Jet_family) as possible candidates. The 190/195 have a stretched fuselage and to me fit the one in the picture better.

So I guess this is an Embraer 190 or 195. Both are very similar, so I am not able to narrow this down more.

[image: Embraer 175 from below]

Embraer 175 from below (picture [source](https://aviationinfocus.files.wordpress.com/2019/04/n101du.jpg)). I could not locate more than side views of the E 190, so an E 175 has to suffice here.

Comment: The prominent "bulge" on the bottom of the fuselage under the wing-- i.e. the way the wing-to-fuselage fairing is so prominent when seen from below-- also seems to be a relevant id feature.

Comment: I added the location, date and time.